# IE 11 form doesn't display div inside <form> other IE versions works well

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-11

I have form
IE 11 form doesn't display div inside  other IE versions, IE11 doesn't display

```
<form>
  <div class="category-dropdown dropdown">
    <span class="old">
      <select class="search-category-dropdown" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value" id="1">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

IE11 reads form inside:

```
<form>
<select class="search-category-dropdown" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: `Span` and `select` are not closed.

Comment: IE doesn't read any div or span inside:           <form>
<select class="search-category-dropdown" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</form>

Comment: https://validator.nu

Comment: Well did you try closing the `span` and `select`? `<span class="old"></span>` and `<select><option value="">1</option><option value="">2</option></select>`

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your HTML code . You have span that not closed and closing tag for div at the bottom that doesn’t have matching element. Please fix your markup and test again.

Comment: thanks, it's error is not in not closed span...IE reads code without any div or span